# Code efficiency, many tap gesture recognizers

Tags: ios, swift, performance, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have built a memory matching game for my app (see picture below)

[image: Memory game]

Each card in the memory game is a UIImageView. My question is the following.  To build this game, I added 16 gesture recognizers, 16 outlets, and 16 functions (1 per gesture recognizer).  However this seems very inefficient. My question is, how this gesture recognizer and outlet issue could be made more simple? what if I had a 100 by 100 grid, would I need to make 100 different outlets and gesture recognizers for each one? This seems inefficient.   I can't post all of my code here but I will post my gesture recognizers so you can get an idea of what I am talking about.

```
@IBOutlet weak var R1C1: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var R1C2: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var R1C3: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var R1C4: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var R2C1: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var R2C2: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var R2C3: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var R2C4: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var R3C1: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var R3C2: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var R3C3: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var R3C4: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var R4C1: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var R4C2: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var R4C3: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var R4C4: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadCards()
   let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
   R1C1.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

   let tapGestureRecognizer2 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped2(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
   R1C2.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer2)

    let tapGestureRecognizer3 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped3(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
    R1C3.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer3)

    let tapGestureRecognizer4 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped4(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
    R1C4.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer4)

    let tapGestureRecognizer5 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped5(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
    R2C1.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer5)

    let tapGestureRecognizer6 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped6(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
    R2C2.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer6)

    let tapGestureRecognizer7 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped7(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
    R2C3.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer7)

    let tapGestureRecognizer8 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped8(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
    R2C4.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer8)

    let tapGestureRecognizer9 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped9(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
    R3C1.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer9)

    let tapGestureRecognizer10 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped10(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
    R3C2.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer10)

    let tapGestureRecognizer11 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped11(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
    R3C3.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer11)

    let tapGestureRecognizer12 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped12(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
    R3C4.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer12)

    let tapGestureRecognizer13 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped13(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
    R4C1.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer13)

    let tapGestureRecognizer14 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped14(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
    R4C2.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer14)

    let tapGestureRecognizer15 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped15(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
    R4C3.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer15)

    let tapGestureRecognizer16 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped16(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
    R4C4.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer16)

    //end viewDidLoad method
}

func imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
UIImageView.transition(with: R1C1, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionFlipFromTop, animations: nil, completion: nil)
let imagePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: newItemList[0].image, ofType: "png")
R1C1.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath!)
memoryArray[0][0].cardIsRevealed = true
memoryArray[0][0].cardImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath!)!
memoryArray[0][0].sound = newItemList[0].image
R1C1.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
count += 1
R1C1.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
twoCardsRevealed()
}
func imageTapped2(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    UIImageView.transition(with: R1C2, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionFlipFromTop, animations: nil, completion: nil)
    let imagePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: newItemList[1].image, ofType: "png")
    R1C2.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath!)
    memoryArray[0][1].cardIsRevealed = true
    memoryArray[0][1].cardImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath!)!
    memoryArray[0][1].sound = newItemList[1].image
    R1C2.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    count += 1
    R1C2.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    twoCardsRevealed()
}
func imageTapped3(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    UIImageView.transition(with: R1C3, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionFlipFromTop, animations: nil, completion: nil)
    let imagePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: newItemList[2].image, ofType: "png")
    R1C3.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath!)
    memoryArray[0][2].cardIsRevealed = true
    memoryArray[0][2].cardImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath!)!
    memoryArray[0][2].sound = newItemList[2].image
    R1C3.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    count += 1
    R1C3.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    twoCardsRevealed()
}
func imageTapped4(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
     UIImageView.transition(with: R1C4, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionFlipFromTop, animations: nil, completion: nil)
    let imagePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: newItemList[3].image, ofType: "png")
    R1C4.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath!)
    R1C4.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    memoryArray[0][3].cardIsRevealed = true
    memoryArray[0][3].cardImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath!)!
    memoryArray[0][3].sound = newItemList[3].image
    count += 1
    R1C4.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    twoCardsRevealed()
}
func imageTapped5(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    UIImageView.transition(with: R2C1, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionFlipFromTop, animations: nil, completion: nil)
    let imagePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: newItemList[4].image, ofType: "png")
    R2C1.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath!)
    R2C1.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    memoryArray[1][0].cardIsRevealed = true
    memoryArray[1][0].cardImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath!)!
    memoryArray[1][0].sound = newItemList[4].image
    count += 1
    R2C1.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    twoCardsRevealed()
}
func imageTapped6(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    UIImageView.transition(with: R2C2, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionFlipFromTop, animations: nil, completion: nil)
    let imagePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: newItemList[5].image, ofType: "png")
    R2C2.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath!)
    R2C2.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    memoryArray[1][1].cardIsRevealed = true
    memoryArray[1][1].cardImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath!)!
    memoryArray[1][1].sound = newItemList[5].image
    count += 1
    R2C2.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    twoCardsRevealed()
}
func imageTapped7(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    UIImageView.transition(with: R2C3, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionFlipFromTop, animations: nil, completion: nil)
    let imagePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: newItemList[6].image, ofType: "png")
    R2C3.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath!)
    R2C3.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    memoryArray[1][2].cardIsRevealed = true
    memoryArray[1][2].cardImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath!)!
    memoryArray[1][2].sound = newItemList[6].image
    count += 1
    R2C3.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    twoCardsRevealed()
}
func imageTapped8(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    UIImageView.transition(with: R2C4, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionFlipFromTop, animations: nil, completion: nil)
    let imagePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: newItemList[7].image, ofType: "png")
    R2C4.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath!)
    R2C4.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    memoryArray[1][3].cardIsRevealed = true
    memoryArray[1][3].cardImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath!)!
    memoryArray[1][3].sound = newItemList[7].image
    count += 1
    R2C4.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    twoCardsRevealed()
}
func imageTapped9(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    UIImageView.transition(with: R3C1, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionFlipFromTop, animations: nil, completion: nil)
    let imagePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: newItemList[8].image, ofType: "png")
    R3C1.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath!)
    R3C1.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    memoryArray[2][0].cardIsRevealed = true
    memoryArray[2][0].cardImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath!)!
    memoryArray[2][0].sound = newItemList[8].image
    count += 1
    R3C1.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    twoCardsRevealed()
}
func imageTapped10(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    UIImageView.transition(with: R3C2, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionFlipFromTop, animations: nil, completion: nil)
    let imagePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: newItemList[9].image, ofType: "png")
    R3C2.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath!)
    R3C2.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    memoryArray[2][1].cardIsRevealed = true
    memoryArray[2][1].cardImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath!)!
    memoryArray[2][1].sound = newItemList[9].image
    count += 1
    R3C2.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    twoCardsRevealed()
}
func imageTapped11(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    UIImageView.transition(with: R3C3, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionFlipFromTop, animations: nil, completion: nil)
    let imagePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: newItemList[10].image, ofType: "png")
    R3C3.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath!)
    R3C3.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    memoryArray[2][2].cardIsRevealed = true
    memoryArray[2][2].cardImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath!)!
    memoryArray[2][2].sound = newItemList[10].image
    count += 1
    R3C3.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    twoCardsRevealed()
}
func imageTapped12(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    UIImageView.transition(with: R3C4, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionFlipFromTop, animations: nil, completion: nil)
    let imagePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: newItemList[11].image, ofType: "png")
    R3C4.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath!)
    R3C4.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    memoryArray[2][3].cardIsRevealed = true
    memoryArray[2][3].cardImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath!)!
    memoryArray[2][3].sound = newItemList[11].image
    count += 1
    R3C4.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    twoCardsRevealed()
}
func imageTapped13(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    UIImageView.transition(with: R4C1, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionFlipFromTop, animations: nil, completion: nil)
    let imagePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: newItemList[12].image, ofType: "png")
    R4C1.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath!)
    R4C1.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    memoryArray[3][0].cardIsRevealed = true
    memoryArray[3][0].cardImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath!)!
    memoryArray[3][0].sound = newItemList[12].image
    count += 1
    R4C1.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    twoCardsRevealed()
}
func imageTapped14(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    UIImageView.transition(with: R4C2, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionFlipFromTop, animations: nil, completion: nil)
    let imagePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: newItemList[13].image, ofType: "png")
    R4C2.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath!)
    R4C2.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    memoryArray[3][1].cardIsRevealed = true
    memoryArray[3][1].cardImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath!)!
   memoryArray[3][1].sound = newItemList[13].image
    count += 1
    R4C2.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    twoCardsRevealed()
}
func imageTapped15(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    UIImageView.transition(with: R4C3, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionFlipFromTop, animations: nil, completion: nil)
    let imagePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: newItemList[14].image, ofType: "png")
    R4C3.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath!)
    R4C3.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    memoryArray[3][2].cardIsRevealed = true
    memoryArray[3][2].cardImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath!)!
    memoryArray[3][2].sound = newItemList[14].image
    count += 1
    R4C3.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    twoCardsRevealed()
}
func imageTapped16(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    UIImageView.transition(with: R4C4, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionFlipFromTop, animations: nil, completion: nil)
    let imagePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: newItemList[15].image, ofType: "png")
    R4C4.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath!)
    R4C4.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    memoryArray[3][3].cardIsRevealed = true
    memoryArray[3][3].cardImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath!)!
    memoryArray[3][3].sound = newItemList[15].image
    count += 1
    R4C4.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    twoCardsRevealed()
}
```

Comment: Can't you use UICollectionView for this kind of UI ? And use didSelect ?

Comment: All of those functions could be replaced by a single one with the right arguments. You could subclass the gesture recognisers so they held a reference to the ImageView and/or memory array.

Comment: @Chris, the gestureRecognizers already know the view they are attached to.  You access it through their `view` property.

Comment: @vacawama Ah yes of course - I forgot about that! Thanks :)

Comment: You can set the `tag` property of the `UIImageView`s to note where they are in the grid.  `imageView.tag = row*100 + col`.  Then in `func imageTapped`: `let view = tapGestureRecognizer.view as! UIImageView`; `let  row = view.tag / 100; let col = view.tag % 100`